# Reading UTF8 file, gives diamond with question mark on unknown characters

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a file I am reading from to acquire a database of music files, like this;

```
00 6F 74 72 6B 00 00 02 57 74 74 79 70 00 00 00  .otrk...Wttyp...
06 00 6D 00 70 00 33 70 66 69 6C 00 00 00 98 00  ..m.p.3pfil...~.
44 00 69.............                            D.i.....
```

Etc., there could be hundreds to thousands of records in this file, all split at "otrk" into a string this is the start of a new track.

The problem actually lies in the above, all the tracks start with otrk, and the has field identifiers, their length, and value, for example above;

```
ttyp = type, and 06 following it is the length of the value, which is .m.p.3 or 00 6D 00 70 00 33
```

then the next field identifier is pfil = filename, this lies the issue, specifically the length, which value is 98, however when read into a string becomes unrecognizable and defaults to a diamond with a question mark, and a value of 239, which is wrong. How can I avoid this and get the correct value in order to display the value correctly.

My code to read the file;

```
 db_file = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

and the code to split and sort through the file

```
string[] entries = content.Split(new string[] "otrk", StringSplitOptions.None);

public List<Songs> Songs { get; } = new List<Songs>();

foreach(string entry in entries)
{
    Songs.Add(Song.Create(entry));
}
```

Song.Create looks like;

```
 public static Song Create(string dbString)
 {
     
    Song toRet = new Song();

    for (int farthestReached = 0; farthestReached < dbString.Length;)
    {
            
       int startOfString = -1;
       int iLength = -1;
       byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0");

        //Gets the start index
        foreach(var l in labels)
        {

            startOfString = dbString.IndexOf(l, farthestReached);

            if (startOfString >= 0)
            {
                    
                // get identifer index plus its length
                iLength = startOfString + 3;                        
                var valueIndex = iLength + 5;
                // get length of value
                string temp = dbString.Substring(iLength + 4, 1);
        
                b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp);

                int xLen = b[0];
                    
                // populate the label
                string fieldLabel = dbString.Substring(startOfString, l.Length);
                // populate the value
                string fieldValue = dbString.Substring(valueIndex, xLen);                        
                   
                // set new
                farthestReached = xLen + valueIndex;

                switch (fieldLabel[0])
                {
                    case 'p':
                    case 't':
                        string stringValue = "";
                         foreach (char c in fieldValue)
                         {
                            if (c == 0)
                                continue;
                            stringValue += c;
                         }

                         assignStringField(toRet, fieldLabel, stringValue);
                         break;
                }
                    
                break;
            }
        }

        //If a field was not found, there are no more fields
        if (startOfString == -1)
            break;             
    }

    return toRet;
}
```

Comment: So the basic format is `{ byte[4] recordType, int32 len (LE), byte[len] };`? and an 'otrk' record contains other nested records with the same structure?

Comment: So is that this file format? https://github.com/Holzhaus/serato-tags/blob/master/scripts/database_v2.py

Comment: File.ReadAllText is the wrong thing to do to this file. It looks like an ID3v2 tag; don't bother inventing your own wheel for it if so; https://id3.org/Implementations

Comment: Jeremy, yes. 
Caius, this is NOT an mp3 file, this is a database file from a program called Serato.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not a UTF-8 file. The hex dump shown in the question makes it clear that it is not a UTF-8 file, and neither a proper text file in any other text encoding. It rather looks like some binary (serialized) format, with data fields of different types.

You cannot reliably read a binary file naively like a text file, especially considering that certain UTF-8 characters are represented by two or more bytes. Thus, it is pretty likely that the UTF-8 decoder will get confused by all the binary data and might miss the first character(s) of a text field because preceding (binary) byte not belonging to a text field could coincidentally be equal to a start byte of a multi-byte character sequence in UTF-8, thus accidentally not correctly identifying the first character(s) in a text field because the UTF-8 decoder is trying to decode a multi-byte sequence not aligning with the text field.

Not only that, but certain byte values or byte sequences are not valid UTF-8 encodings for character, and you would "lose" such bytes when trying to read them as UTF-8 text.

Also, since it is possible for byte sequences of multiple bytes to form a single UTF-8 character, you cannot rely on every individual byte being turned into a character with the same ordinal value (even if the byte value might be a valid ASCII value), since such a byte could be decoded "merely" as part of a UTF-8 byte sequence into a single character whose ordinal value is entirely different from the value of the bytes in such a byte sequence.

That said, as far as i can tell, the text field in your litte data snippet above does not look like UTF-8 at all. `00 6D 00 70 00 33` (`*m*p*3`) and `00 44 00 69` (`*D*i`) are definitely not UTF-8 -- note the zero bytes.

Thus, first consult the file format specification to figure out the actual text encoding used for the text fields in this file format. **Don't** guess. **Don't** assume. **Don't** believe. Look up, verify and confirm.

Secondly, since the file is not a proper text file (as already mentioned), you cannot read it like a text file with File.ReadAllText. Instead, read the raw byte data, for example with File.ReadAllBytes.

Find the `otrk` marker in the byte data of the file not as text, but by the 4 byte values this marker is made of.

Then, parse the byte data following the `otrk` marker according to the file format specification, and **only** decode the bytes that are actual text data into strings, using the correct text encoding as denoted by the file format specification.

Comment: You misunderstand it is NOT a music file,  it contains a list of music files.

Comment: Alright, i stand corrected. But it still is not a proper text file, as the hex dump in your question makes obvious. The recommendation in my answer remains the same: You need to read the file in a binary manner. Consult the specification of the file format you are trying to read, and follow it by the letter...